# Firestore where function not working as expected in Ionic / Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the `User` collection within my firestore database:

[image]

I am trying to use the below method to only return `Users` where `isMechanic === false`:

```
private _mechanics = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);

  get mechanics() {
    return this._mechanics.asObservable();
  }

 return of(
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("isMechanic", "==", "false")
        .get()
        .then((docs) => {
          const data = []
          docs.forEach((doc) => {
            data.push(doc);
          });
          this._mechanics.next(data)
          console.log('Mechanics in UsersService:', this._mechanics);
          console.log('Mechanics in UsersService:', this.mechanics);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    );
```

No records are currently beingWhen this method is called, an empty array is logged to the console. So no records are being returned even though (as per screenshot) isMechanic is `false` for this record.

Can someone please tell me what changes are required for this function to work as expected?

Comment: first of all, where is `isMechanic` in users?

Comment: It's not working because `isMechanic` isn't a property on the objects in the array. Have you tried looking in the nested properties to see where the property is? For example, in `metadata`. I don't use Firestore, but I imagine this should be documented in the official documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out just now.

If I replace `"false"` with `false`, then the `users` collection is filtered as expected.

Replacing

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("isMechanic", "==", "false")
```

with

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("isMechanic", "==", false)
```

returns only `users` where `isMechanic == false`

Answer (score 0):

> LoadedMechanics is an empty array:

Then surely `user.isMechanic` is either `undefined` or `null`

Look at the following example

```js
let data = [
{
},
{
   IsMechanic: undefined
},
{
   IsMechanic: null
},
{
   IsMechanic: false
}
]

console.log(data)

data = data.filter(pr => pr.IsMechanic === false)

console.log(data)
```

`filter` function ignored most the cases.

Now the question is, what is `users` object? It looks like an array of documents for me.
Usually to get all properties from document you have to use ...data() function.

```js
users.map(user => ({
  id: user.id,
  ...user.data()
}))
```

did you do that in your `this.usersService.users` observable?

--Edit

You could change following code

```js
const data = []
docs.forEach((doc) => {
data.push(doc);
this._mechanics.next(data);
});
```

to

```js
const data = docs.docs.map(doc => ({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}));
this._mechanics.next(data);
```

Also according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

You should filter boolean properties using literal values, not double quote them

`.where("isMechanic", "==", "false")`

`.where("isMechanic", "==", false)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question above as I'm going to try to filter the data when querying it in firebase rather than loading all users initially when there's no need

Comment: Updated an answer. `get()` function in this case returns a `query` object which contains props like `empty`, `docs`. You get map all documents into new array of objects with `.map(doc => ({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}));`